# Download file from local directory?

Tags: vb.net, iis, webforms

I have a website set up in IIS and a csv file in the root directory.  How can I make it so clicking a button will download the file?

```
sub dl(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Using client as New System.Net.WebClient()

        client.DownloadFile("/", "some_file.csv")

    End Using

end sub

<asp:Button ID="btn_dl" Text="Download" OnClick="dl" runat="server" />
```

It seems no matter what I put into the first parameter of client.DownloadFile, I always get this exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\some_file.csv' is denied
```

Is there a way to make this work or even a different method?

Comment: As the exception said, it doesn't have permission to access the file in "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv". You can try to change the path of "some_file.csv". Additionally, the first parameter of DownloadFile is URI address.

Comment: But even if I give the absolute path of the file (e.g. www.example.com/path/some_file.csv) then I still get the same exception

Comment: I have  tested your code. If you have deployed it on local IIS, you should both set url and identity of application pool.